# Do floating islands exists in pre-hardmode?

Tags: terraria

My friend says that Floating islands are in pre-hardmode, but I can't find them. Do floating islands exist in pre-hardmode?

Comment: I'd love to answer, but your grammar has me confused as to what you're actually asking. If English is not your first language, may I suggest typing your question in your native language and running it through google translate?

Answer (score 1):

World generation happens when you create the world, which includes generating floating islands

By the time you have found the angler, the floating islands already exist

The quest you received is not to kill something, but most likely to fish for a [Angelfish, Cloudfish, Clownfish, Fallen Starfish, The Fish of Cthulhu, Harpyfish, Pengfish, or Slimefish](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fishing)

Do note that the Angler's quests reset each morning at 4:30am in-game time.